# Where should css go in .html page?

Tags: html, css

I have a index.html page and a style.css file.

I have a style class called `.slider` and a style class called `.logo`. Should I put both `.slider` and `.logo` inside the style.css page or should i put `.slider` in index.html and `.logo` inside .css?

im asking this because i dont know if I should put styles only related to one page inside a global style.css or should i just put it inline in the page it applies to?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you embed css that is page specific. Here is how I do my css:

**Global css (seperate file(s)):**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

**NOTE:** In today's web world we use a ton of plugins/themes and these plugins/themes tend to roll out newer versions so when you override these plugins/themes make sure you create a css file specific to that theme.

For instance,

**Bootstrap 3.1**

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Create this for all your bootstrap overrides so you can use the latest version when it comes out.

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.overrides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**Page specific css(embedded):**

```
<head>
<!-- last element in head //-->
<style type="text/css">
        .pageSpecific
        {
         color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
```

When I am in development stages or the html element does not require css classification.

**Simple style format (inline):**

```
<th style="min-width: 65px;">Column Header</th>
```

You may have **print specific css** as well:

```
  <link href="/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and inside this file wrap your css as such:

```
@media print{
<!-- print specific css here//-->
}
```

Keep in mind that you may want to use a css classifcation at a later date when at the time it may seem page specific. Always code for reusability!

**Finally:**

I like to use [css minifier](https://cssminifier.com/) when I put my file(s) into production. I do the same with my javascript files using [UglyJs](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs). There is also LESS css that you can use but for now I would stick to these simple conventions or something similar.

Comment: Why are you using `media=all`? There is rarely ever any reason for this. Why do your CSS need to be sent to a braillle-reader? Or to print? Why not just use `media=screen, tv, projection` as that is what is really useful for the viewable CSS? (Yes, I know `tv` and `projection` returns a validation error - that hardly matters, since the validator seems to forget kiosk-mode, flight-LCDs and a host of other screens that doesn't adhere to "screen").

Comment: What is the penalty for using this instead of `@media screen`? I want my css to carry over to my print css and I will override in my `@media print` rules if needed. I guess I could put `screen, print` but again, what is the penalty?

Comment: There is no penalty, but normally quite a lot of the CSS used for screen does not belong in print. Usually a completely separate print.css is used, simply because there is a lot of content on a regular webpage that has nothing to do in print - for instance background images covering the page, and so on. Formatting is often also not particularly good for screen vs. printed pages, and other items you might want to hide or emphasize differently. It depends of course a little on the site in question, but most of the time, screen CSS is useless in print, and vice versa.

Comment: Right. That is why I typically remove all styling based on the parent container (for instance, the `.nav-bar` ) in my print css when necessary. TBH, I don't ever use the `@media screen` I use the `@media max/min-width` rule. I probably could omit the `media=all` but I have to admit I just took this from a piece of code laying around on my pc.

Comment: Agreed. `media=screen,tv,projection` (or, in your case, `media=all`) will at least cater to all viewports with visual styling (and all to any others, as well). The point is that if you don't have that declaration on, some (albeit fewer and fewer) browsers / kiosks / web-readers, won't acknowledge the CSS at all, resulting in a broken page.

Comment: I tend to eliminate all errors in my console so I would have a tough time using the screen,tv, projection declaration. I just can't let them pass. lol

Comment: It's a stupid warning, not an error, and dismissing it makes it impossible to view webpages on quite a lot of embedded screens and similar. Not the biggest problem, perhaps, but an idiotic choice from the W3C-goons. But then, the internal BS in that gang is a story for a completely different forum.

Answer (score 2):

Styles can go in one of three places.

1. Inline on the element itself
2. In the html page
3. In a separate file

I would suggest either putting it in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your html or putting it in a separate file, either will work just as well.  Obviously having the styles in a separate file means you could reuse those styles on another page if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Either way, it won't make a difference. Personally, I like to have all of my CSS in one place, but you can do whatever you want. If you do put all of your CSS in one document, use comments to separate it into groups, so everything will be easy to find.

Answer (score -2):

You should NEVER have inline or on-page CSS. It should all go in the stylesheet (of which you should only have one per media-type) - why? Because stylesheets are cached, and the cache is way better to hold it than the HTML-files (which may also be cached, by all means, but with dynamic content, they often load quite more often than CSS).

Second, it's a nightmare to update and change, if not everything is in one file.

Comment: Not true. Sometimes you separate css files for the same project. Not to mention when you are bringing in a theme such as bootstrap you want all your overrides in a single css file. It's very easy to locate where your style format is coming from in your browser's developer tools. Inline I can agree with that but not embedded css. There is nothing wrong with embedded css. I don't want every single page load ciphering through css that it is never going to use even if the cost is minimal.

Comment: First off, you NEVER use shit like Bootstrap. It's pure and utter garbage, overloading both the HTML and CSS with way too much code. Second, the cost of adding all the CSS into one file is minimal, and there is really no point in separating them - a site-wide CSS-file should be max 50KB, and that is the absolute max, everything included. Also, if you do use SCSS/SASS or LESS, having everything separated during dev, and concatinated after rendering, is simple.

Comment: So if you don't use bootstrap then how do you handle responsive? I agree bootstrap has a ton of fluff but my page load time does not suffer by using it. I don't have time to write custom styling for my shop and nor would I want to. Just curious as to how you handle responsiveness.

Comment: I write the HTML and the CSS for the site properly, of course? Using responsive design, it's maybe max a 100 lines of CSS (and that is a LOT) to make the site responsive. I currently am making a file-upload/sharing site, to make it work on every single screen size, I had to add about 20 lines of CSS, and two lines of HTML. If you know what you're doing, Bootstrap is a laugh, it's really, really horrid.

Comment: Okay... so, why was this downvoted? Because the statement is still correct. I understand that some don't understand how HTML, CSS and HTTP works, but that doesn't take away from the fact that quite a few of the other answers, while technically perfectly fine, doesn't really favor proper coding practices.

Comment: I think your answer was downvoted because your answer is more about preference than coding practices. The standard is the standard at which most web programmers follow. Most of us follow the standard set forth by W3C

Comment: Eh, yes? And what about my answer was not standard? ONE CSS file per media target. (Screen, print et al). The use of inline or embedded CSS is considered poor coding practice in production environments, so I can't really see why that would be wrong either. Please elaborate what you think is wrong about my statement?

Comment: I did NOT downvote your answer. Like I said I too take my inline out when moved to production unless its just a simple style change. This user is a new dev and while you say it is poor coding practice it's best for him/her to figure out what works best for him/her as they become more experienced. You don't want to discourage them from using the standard. Just my opinion.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't arguing that you downvoted. I was just wondering what you meant was wrong, if anything. I'm for teaching good coding practices from the get-go, because there are way too many web-jockeys out there with absolutely no clue whatsoever. Inline CSS is fine for prototyping, testing and such, but should be limited to maybe changing stuff with javascript - although I'm more for class-changes and similar recipes. I don't really think it's best for him/her to figure it out on their own, simply because the chance of them making the wrong choice is quite high. And then we have to help again.

Comment: I DID down vote your answer.  Don't tell people to NEVER do things that are very common, your comment about NEVER using things like bootstrap too is just ridiculous.  Bootstrap is fantastic for getting people started and it serves its purpose well.  Dynamic pages these days will often load a static page that then make Ajax requests, this often means that the page can be cached without problems.  While in the past it may have been a problem, it certainly isn't in a lot of cases these days.

Comment: So your claim is that Bootstrap is a "good solution"? There are already thousands of mediocre, or worse, solutions online, too many of them use that monstrosity. Adding three or four times as much HTML as needed (multiple classes all over, for one), and adding the bootstrap-core-CSS on top of that... is not a good solution. It's a little bit like looking at WordPress-code - add them together, and you get real "jewels". And why is "never" a bad word? "Never" is perfectly fine to underline that things shouldn't be done. "Common" does not equal smart, or correct, or standard.

Comment: I'd have to disagree, I do think that Bootstrap is a good solution for a lot of cases.  If you are looking for absolute efficiency then no, it's not, however for the majority of people creating home websites, or even small business websites it is perfectly reasonable. Next thing you will tell us that vuejs, jquery etc etc should NEVER be used because and instead you should write all your JS from scratch.  I would suggest that once you get in the real world, and not just as a hobbyist, you will realise that writing everything from scratch because you think you are better is bad practise.

Comment: While I do think that purely for effectiveness things should be written in pure javascript, I myself use jQuery, as I find it easier than having to write functions for everything I want to do. However, javascript is slightly more complex than HTML and CSS. And there are never (there's that word again) things you should do on a web page that can't be done leaner, faster and better without Bootstrap. I fail to see how using something that deviates from standards, learning that instead, gives anything for simple things as HTML/CSS. Especially looking at all the questions reg. Bootstrap on here.